# Ipad Issue - Modal displaying behind the Overlay

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a custom `bootstrap modal`. It is working fine in Desktop & Mobiles.

But when i open it in `Ipad`, the `modal` opens up but it is `overlayed`. All i can see is black background with opacity & behind this background the modal is seen, it is unclickable.

I also tried increasing the `z-index` for the modal class but nothing happens.

I also tried hiding the class `.modal-backdrop`. This time the black background is gone, but still the `modal` hides behind my main header & left menu.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: does it work on your ipad os/safari version on the bootstrap demo pages?

Comment: can you create a bootply - i've used modals many times on ipad and all good so i suspect something else is causing the issue

Comment: yes...bootstrap demo pages are working.!

Comment: k..i am creating in bootply with my custom css

Answer (score -1):

use the z-index with css the position:relative

Comment: It will dis align the modal, as modal is positioned fixed.